# ClamD server Currently Down

Tags: centos, clamav

I'm getting this error message after install ClamAV from direcadmin message system.
OS: CentOs 5.

**The service 'clamd' on server starhost.net is currently down
This message has been automatically generated notifying you that the service clamd is currently down.**

Why can I get this error for each hour? I checked up cron jobs and I couldn't find any job about it.

How to control Clamd service?

OS: CentOS with DirectAdmin

Comment: I gave this command:

`# service clamd start`
I got this error:

`Starting clamd: LibClamAV Error: cli_loaddb(): No supported database files found in /usr/share/clamav
ERROR: Can't open file or directory`

Comment: When you run `freshclam` and then try to start the `clamd` service, what happens?  `freshclam` should update/download the latest antivirus DB files.

Comment: freshclam -v

It doesn't give any error.

`Current working dir is /var/lib/clamav
Max retries == 3
ClamAV update process started at Sat Jul 28 00:29:17 2012
Using IPv6 aware code
Querying current.cvd.clamav.net
TTL: 94
Software version from DNS: 0.97.5
main.cvd version from DNS: 54
main.cvd is up to date (version: 54, sigs: 1044387, f-level: 60, builder: sven)
daily.cvd version from DNS: 15185
daily.cld is up to date (version: 15185, sigs: 239672, f-level: 63, builder: guitar)
bytecode.cvd version from DNS: 188
bytecode.cvd is up to date (version: 188, sigs: 38, f-level: 63, builder: neo)`

Comment: Ah, freshclam is putting the files into `/var/lib/clamav`.  Check your clamd.conf for what the database directory is set to (presumably /usr/share/clamav), and point it at the location used by freshclam.

Comment: Why freshclam is searching the database in "/var/lib/clamav" directory. How can I change this option? I mean, freschclam update db files to "/var/lib/clamv" but clamd service looking for that files in "usr/share/clamav".

Comment: You can edit the configuration files /etc/clamd.conf or /etc/feshclam.conf, and set the database directories to be the same.  I think `/var/lib/clamav` is actually more appropriate for constantly changing database files, rather than something in /usr/share, actually, so I would change /etc/clamd.conf.

Comment: I throught that I installed clamav twice. One of them `yum install clamav` the other one installed with `./build update clamav`. I thought if I uninstall clamav with `yum remove clamav` and after run `./build update clamav` command the problem will be repair.

Comment: And now, Clamd service working very fine. Thank you very much

Comment: I've consolidated the comments as an Answer, if you can accept it, we'll close out this Question.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a mismatch between the antivirus database directories used by freshclam and clamd.  The `/etc/freshclam.conf` setting`DatabaseDirectory` was apparently pointing to `/var/lib/clamav` (which is default for the package), but the corresponding setting in `/etc/clamd.conf` was pointing to `/usr/share/clamav`.  This mismatch may have been because the OP had compiled clamav on his own.

Once the `DatabaseDirectory` settings were reconciled between the configuration files, `clamd` could see the antivirus database and start up successfully.